# Why are console.log() and console.dir() logging Object properties that don't exist yet?

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

Test the following:

```
var o = {};
console.log(o);
o.prop = 'value';
```

In Firefox 42.0 if you click on the Object that shows up in the console, you should be shocked. Tested in Firebug 2.0.13, as well as the regular console.

Even more shocking, test this:

```
var o = {prop:'test'};
console.log(o);
o.prop = 'value';
```

I could not reproduce this problem in the most recent Microsoft Edge, using the code above, but I was able to produce the same problem with more extensive code.

Using a much larger Object Oriented JavaScript program *(using Construtors)*, I also tested this with `console.dir()` and had the same hoisting issue in Microsoft Edge and Firefox.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not a bug, though it could be considered unintuitive. When you inspect a logged object, you’re inspecting it *as it currently exists* and not as it was when you logged it. To keep the rich inspection *and* ignore future modifications, you’ll have to log a deep copy of the object, which isn’t easy to do.

In this example, a quick (enumerable-own-properties-only into a new `Object`) shallow copy works, though:

```
function copyObject(obj) {
    var result = {};

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        result[key] = obj[key];
    });

    return result;
}

var o = {};
console.log(o);
console.log(copyObject(o));
o.prop = 'value';
```

Comment: Is that also true of `console.dir()`, because I had the same problem when I used more code?

Comment: @PHPglue: Yes, it is. It also is true and *was* maybe even less intuitive (until recently) in Chrome & co., where `console.log` was asynchronous in addition to exhibiting this behaviour, so your example could result in `{ prop: 'value' }` being logged as the “object overview” even without expanding it.

Comment: I tried `if(!Object.create){ Object.create = function(o){ function F(){}; F.prototype = o; return new F;} }`, then I used `Object.create()` and had the same issue.

Comment: @PHPglue: `Object.create` doesn’t copy an object. It creates an object with a given prototype. `var p = { x: 5 }; var q = Object.create(p); p.x = 6; q.x` will result in `6`, for example.

Comment: I found a solution for my usage, but was wondering if this was a bug. It looks like some kind of synchronicity issue. My function that I already made does that kind of thing recursively. Thanks. I'm unhappy with the Browser vendors, but will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment:

```
var o = {};
console.log('logged' + o);
o.prop = 'value';
```

Results:

```
logged Object {}
"value"
```

So, where do you see its logging 'value'?

Comment: You must not have tested it in Firefox 42.0. Tested in regular `console` and firebug `console`.

Answer (score -1):

You must be confused between the `console.log()` and `console.dir()` functions.

`console.log(o)` prints the object reference. So by the time you expand it in the console, you'll see all the updates that have been done on it so far

`console.dir(o)` is like a snapshot of the reference at that time. This way you won't be able to see the updates that have been done in a later time in the console

Comment: Take a look at my second example.

Comment: It is not a bug! That's what the intention of console.log is. To give a reference in the console to the object. By the time you expand the object, all the updates will be reflected. It's like deferring the output until you want to see it. Try console.dir and tell me if the "bug" exists

Comment: Why does the second example show results of `{prop: "test"}` in the latest version of Microsoft Edge then, if that is what it's supposed to do?

Comment: I have never used Microsoft edge. Your question was related to the unexpected behaviour in Mozilla Firefox

Comment: Reread the question. I don't think we should expect that behavior. Let's face it Mozilla even capitalizes things like `console` and `window` in their docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window . This makes them appear unprofessional.

Comment: It serves its own purpose. that's why we have the console.dir for overcoming the behaviour

Comment: Using another much larger JavaScript programming example `console.dir()` had the same hoisting issue.

Comment: @PHPglue: You’re aware that `Console` and `Window` are types, yes? Where `console` and `window` are instances of each? Using the capitalized type names to refer to methods on their prototypes is completely correct.

Comment: Not as far as a JavaScript Programmer is concerned. `console.log(Console); console.log(Window)` in Firebug. I tried `new Console` as well. `Window` does console, as does `Window.prototype`, but `new Window` does not work. The bottom line is that Mozilla needs to make their docs more intuitive for the user.

Comment: `@Ryan O'Hara` check this out. [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) has some methods as properties of `Array.prototype` while others are not. Please explain.